# best way of handling varying iDevice widths?

Tags: ios8

I'm wondering if anyone can provide some insight as to how to handle varying device sizes when designing in storyboard.

Do you have to check for device frame size before drawing views then?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about it. If you insist on using frames, you would want to check the frame size before drawing your views. One way you could go about it is writing a method in your utils file that will check for the device, something like this:

```
+ (NSString *)getHardwareModel {
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate_iPhone = (AppDelegate_iPhone *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    size_t size;
    // get the size of the returned device name
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    // allocate the space to store name
    char *machine = (char*)malloc(size);
    // get the device name
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    // place the name into a NSString
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    free(machine);

    appDelegate_iPhone.hardwareModel = platform;

    return platform;
}
```

Once we get back what device we are using, we can then set the frame accordingly. So if I wanted to check for say the iPhone6 device, I would do something like this in my setFrameSize method:

```
NSString *hardwareVersion = [Utils getHardwareModel];
    NSString *target=@"x86_64";
    NSString *deviceTarget=@"iPhone7,1";
    NSRange range =[hardwareVersion rangeOfString:target ];
    NSRange deviceRange =[hardwareVersion rangeOfString:deviceTarget ];
    NSLog(@"device=%@",hardwareVersion);

    // Setting the frame size for the progress bar


        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
            if (range.location!=NSNotFound ||deviceRange.location!=NSNotFound) {
                float frameSize =  self.view.frame.size.width;
                NSLog(@"Frame width===%f", frameSize);
                self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 85);
            }
```

Another way that would avoid all of this is to use autolayout and set constraints based on the different screen sizes. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html